# aws cli signature version 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to move all my data from `Bucket1` of account `A` to `Bucket2` of account `B`.

For this:

1. I downloaded `AWS CLI` for Windows.
2. Entered `IAM` credentials using command `aws configure` (these credentials are from account `B`)
3. Run command to sync buckets: `aws s3 sync s3://Bucket1 s3://Bucket2`

   I received following error:

> fatal error: An error occured (InvalidRequest) when calling the ListObject operation: You are attempting to operate on a bucket in a region that requires Signature Version 4. You can fix this issue by explicitly providing the correct region location using the --region argument, the AWS_DEFAULT_REGION environment variable, or the region variable in the AWS CLI configuration file. You can get the bucket's location by running "aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket BUCKET".

How to tackle this error?

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.61 Python/2.7.9 windows/8 botocore/1.5.24
```

Comment: As the error says, you should add a `--region` parameter to your `aws s3 sync` command. I think you need to reference the *destination* region, but if that doesn't work, try the *source* region. It will be in the format like `us-east-1` or `us-west-2`. Which regions are you using?

Comment: how to add region parameter (syntax)? I receive `too few arguments` error on command `aws --region us-west-2 `

Comment: `aws s3 sync s3://Bucket1 s3://Bucket2 --region us-west-2`

Comment: `Bucket1` is in `us-east-1` and `Bucket2` is in `us-west-2`. First i tried command: `aws s3 sync s3://Bucket1 s3://Bucket2 --region us-west-2` then I tried `aws s3 sync s3://Bucket1 s3://Bucket2 --region us-east-1` but same error both times (error is mentioned in question)

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem. I create a bucket in `us-east-1` and `us-west-2`. I then issued the `aws s3 sync s3://Bucket1 s3://Bucket2` command and it worked fine. I even tried adding `--region` with various values and it continued to work fine. I'm using the latest CLI `aws-cli/1.11.63 Python/2.7.9 Windows/2008ServerR2 botocore/1.5.26` on an Amazon EC2 instance with credentials via a Role assigned to the Instance. So, I was unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: You added these buckets to two different accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `S3` url was like :`https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-east-1`
so I supposed that `us-east-1` is my region but actually it was not!

I used AWS command to find `Bucket2` region and it told me a different region.

Then I used this command `aws s3 sync s3://Bucket1 s3://Bucket2 --region Asia Pacific (Mumbai)` and everything worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Look for the correct region of the bucket (see attached image).
Try the command below by specifying the correct region:

```
aws s3 ls --region us-west-2
```

[image]

S3 is global - don't let that mislead you.